# pulse audio system sounds not working, but cards work with alsa

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I am pulling my hair out with this one. I have been working on it solidly for over a day, following every article I can find.

### History:

I built a new machine for lockdown (Ubuntu 20.04 exclusively). Fairly high-end, but standard.

- Powered speakers running from rear line-out port and generic usb webcam (for zoom meetings, relevant as camera has built in mic). So far so good everything works, kinda.
- The web cam mic was poor quality, so got a cheap USB mic, also poor quality, but worked.
- Decided to use an existing cardioid mic I had. So got a Shure motiv mvi XLR to USB device. This is where issues started. No matter what I did (due to the Shure having a headphone out for monitoring purposes) Ubuntu saw it as a valid sink and, being USB, kept setting it to the default output.

I tried numerous things and eventually found the hacky solution of running the following as a startup application:

```
pactl set-default-sink pactl set-default-sink
```

(Looks weird, but a forum recommended it and it worked.) A couple of months later after many system updates, I discovered I no longer needed the "startup application" and disabled it.

Fast forward to yesterday, and my current issue. I decided to buy an external DAC (cambridge audio Dacmagic plus) and now I get no system sounds at all, web browsers etc. In the `settings > sounds` screen the Default devices are listed correctly, but clicking "test" and pressing the speaker buttons makes no sound.

Running `lsUSB`, I can see the devices.

Running `aplay -L`, the devices are listed:

```
surround21
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=C10
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=C10,DEV=0
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=C10,DEV=0
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=C10,DEV=0
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=C10,DEV=0
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=C10,DEV=0
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=C10,DEV=0
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=C10,DEV=0
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=C10,DEV=0
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=C10,DEV=0
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=C10,DEV=0
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=C10,DEV=0
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=C10,DEV=0
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
usbstream:CARD=C10
    Cambridge Audio USB Audio 1.0
    USB Stream Output
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
usbstream:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH
    USB Stream Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Hardware device with all software conversions
usbstream:CARD=NVidia
    HDA NVidia
    USB Stream Output
sysdefault:CARD=MVi
    Shure MVi, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=MVi,DEV=0
    Shure MVi, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=MVi,DEV=0
    Shure MVi, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=MVi,DEV=0
    Shure MVi, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=MVi,DEV=0
    Shure MVi, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=MVi,DEV=0
    Shure MVi, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=MVi,DEV=0
    Shure MVi, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=MVi,DEV=0
    Shure MVi, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=MVi,DEV=0
    Shure MVi, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=MVi,DEV=0
    Shure MVi, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=MVi,DEV=0
    Shure MVi, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=MVi,DEV=0
    Shure MVi, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=MVi,DEV=0
    Shure MVi, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
usbstream:CARD=MVi
    Shure MVi
    USB Stream Output
usbstream:CARD=Camera
    UVC Camera
    USB Stream Output
```

- Running `aplay -D plughw:C10 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` and it plays (C10 is the dac name)
- Running `speaker-test -c 2 -D plughw:C10` and I get sound out of each speaker in turn.
- Even running zoom if I pick the DAC in the settings everything works perfectly
- However running `speaker-test -c 2 -D default` or `speaker-test -c 2 -D pulse` and I get:

```
speaker-test 1.2.2 

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 96 to 1048576
Period size range from 32 to 349526
Using max buffer size 1048576
Periods = 4
ALSA lib pcm_pulse.c:752:(pulse_prepare) PulseAudio: Unable to create stream: No such entity 

Unable to set hw params for playback: Input/output error
Setting of hwparams failed: Input/output error
```

If I run `aplay -D default  /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` I get:

```
ALSA lib pcm_pulse.c:752:(pulse_prepare) PulseAudio: Unable to create stream: No such entity

aplay: set_params:1407: Unable to install hw params:
ACCESS:  RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  S16_LE
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: 16
FRAME_BITS: 16
CHANNELS: 1
RATE: 48000
PERIOD_TIME: 125000
PERIOD_SIZE: 6000
PERIOD_BYTES: 12000
PERIODS: 4
BUFFER_TIME: 500000
BUFFER_SIZE: 24000
BUFFER_BYTES: 48000
TICK_TIME: [0 0]
```

- I have tried numerous suggestions such as reinstalling and re-initializing `pulseaudio` and `alsa_base`.
- I have made numerous adjustments to the config files in isolation based on various threads and posts.
- I have checked `pavucontrol` and used `alsamixer`. Various "fixes" have made things worse and been reverted, but always still have the issue.
- I have tried restarting the pulse daemon many times and it starts without error.

I know it is going to be something stupid and obvious. :)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar problem (and thanks for posting - it really helped me move forward)

Answer (score -1):

I can't answer you question. However, I've asked a question in a similar way before and got  now answers. Try using https://paste.ubuntu.com/ or a similar service, and provide links to your terminal output. I think these questions with lots of text tend to put people off.